# My Carousel Materialize doesn't work. I'm using latest version 1.0.0

Tags: javascript, css, carousel, materialize, css-frameworks

My problem is my carousel didn't show up. It appears just white like there's nothing.
This is my html code for carousel materialize.. It is from their site http://materializecss.com/carousel.html

```
   <div class="carousel carousel-slider center">
            <div class="carousel-fixed-item center">
              <a class="btn waves-effect white grey-text darken-text-2">button</a>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item red white-text" href="#one!">
              <h2>First Panel</h2>
              <p class="white-text">This is your first panel</p>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item amber white-text" href="#two!">
              <h2>Second Panel</h2>
              <p class="white-text">This is your second panel</p>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item green white-text" href="#three!">
              <h2>Third Panel</h2>
              <p class="white-text">This is your third panel</p>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item blue white-text" href="#four!">
              <h2>Fourth Panel</h2>
              <p class="white-text">This is your fourth panel</p>
            </div>
          </div>
```

And here's my javascript for the carousel that also a code from their site and it's located at the bottom of my body tag.

```
var instance = M.Carousel.init({
fullWidth: true});

// Or with jQuery

$('.carousel.carousel-slider').carousel({
fullWidth: true
});
```

To be specific, here's my links for my materialize and js.

```
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "materialize/css/materialize.css">
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "materialize/css/materialize.min.css">
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "css/style.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>     
<script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.3/js/materialize.min.js"></script>       



<script type = "text/javascript" src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>    
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/news.js"></script>         
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the carousel element

`var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel');`

and then pass it as parameter when you initialize it.

```
var instances = M.Carousel.init(elems, options);
```